# Redefinition in C++, previous definition in header file?

Tags: c++, header, include, guard, redefinition

So I am confused. I am getting a redefinition error when trying to implement a method previously declared in a header file. I added include guards to the header and still got the same error. If someone could explain to me what I am not seeing, that would be fantastic.

> In file included from main.cpp:2:
>           ./thing.cpp:7:12: error: redefinition of 'method'
>           int Thing::method(void)
>                      ^
>           ./thing.hpp:12:6: note: previous definition is here
>                   int method(void) {};
>                       ^

**--EDIT--**

I am now getting the following:

> duplicate symbol __ZN5Thing6methodEv in:
>       main.o
>       thing.o ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

**thing.hpp:**

```
#ifndef THING_H
#define THING_H

class Thing {

public:
        int a;
        int b;
        char c;

        int method(void) {};
        Thing(int anA, int aB, char aC): a(anA), b(aB), c(aC) {};


};

#endif
```

**thing.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "thing.hpp"

using namespace std;

int Thing::method(void)
{
        return 5;

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "thing.cpp"

using namespace std;

Thing* thing = new Thing(5,5,'c');

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
        cout << thing->method() <<endl;

}
```

Comment: why are you including `thing.cpp` in main.cpp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your header file you have:

```
int method(void) {};
```

That's an inline definition, not a declaration. The `{}` is actually providing the (albeit empty) function body to the compiler. Remove the `{}` if you want to define the function in another file.

Additionally, you have `#include "thing.cpp"` rather than `#include "thing.hpp"` at the top of your `main.cpp` file.

Answer (score 1):

In main.cpp you need to change:

```
#include "thing.cpp"
```

to:

```
#include "thing.hpp"
```